# how to formating in right or properly way MySQL

Tags: mysql

assume i have codes like this

```
SELECT * from mytable WHERE rowNumber = 4;
```

and here's the results (no real results, just ilustration)

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+----------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+------------------+-------------------+----------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------+----------+---------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+
| rowNumber | printStatus | reprintDetailId | reprintDetail               | expeditionName | printedDate         | awbCode  | orderNumbers | buyerName     | buyerAddress                                                                            | buyerMobile  | oldStockKeepingUnit | stockKeepingUnit | productName       | kategori | koliNumbers | orderPackNumber | orderPackName | orderItemQuantity | unitName | productWeight | weightUnitName | deliverySchedule | sameday_code |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+----------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+------------------+-------------------+----------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------+----------+---------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+
| 4         | REPRINT     | 4               | pengembalian barang(refund) | JAKSEL         | 2020-11-13 17:51:36 | 94148181 | 94148181     | Ellin Natalia | Jalan Pati Unus No. 33, Lt. 2, KEBAYORAN BARU, KOTA JAKARTA SELATAN, DKI JAKARTA, 12120 | 089692646971 | 960-931             | 0-09-1-00960     | Ayam Fillet 500g  | REG      | 1           | 3.00            | 0.5 Kg        | 1.50              | kg       | 1.50          | Kg             | -                | PHS          |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+----------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+------------------+-------------------+----------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------+----------+---------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+
|           | REPRINT     | 4               | pengembalian barang(refund) | JAKSEL         | 2020-11-13 17:51:36 | 94148181 | 94148181     | Ellin Natalia | Jalan Pati Unus No. 33, Lt. 2, KEBAYORAN BARU, KOTA JAKARTA SELATAN, DKI JAKARTA, 12120 | 089692646971 | 961-932             | 0-09-1-00961     | Ayam Kampung 650g | REG      | 1           | 1.00            | 0.65 Kg       | 0.65              | kg       | 0.65          | Kg             | -                | PHS          |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+----------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+------------------+-------------------+----------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------+----------+---------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+
|           | REPRINT     | 4               | pengembalian barang(refund) | JAKSEL         | 2020-11-13 17:51:36 | 94148181 | 94148181     | Ellin Natalia | Jalan Pati Unus No. 33, Lt. 2, KEBAYORAN BARU, KOTA JAKARTA SELATAN, DKI JAKARTA, 12120 | 089692646971 | 961-932             | 0-09-1-00961     | Ayam Kampung 650g | REG      | 2           | 3.00            | 0.65 Kg       | 1.95              | kg       | 1.95          | Kg             | -                | PHS          |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+----------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+------------------+-------------------+----------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------+----------+---------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+
```

so that are the data for rowNumber = 4, which part of my codes should i change so the value who comes double will be depreciated into just 1 value because there's same value and same means

expected results

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+----------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+------------------+-------------------+----------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------+----------+---------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+
| rowNumber | printStatus | reprintDetailId | reprintDetail               | expeditionName | printedDate         | awbCode  | orderNumbers | buyerName     | buyerAddress                                                                            | buyerMobile  | oldStockKeepingUnit | stockKeepingUnit | productName       | kategori | koliNumbers | orderPackNumber | orderPackName | orderItemQuantity | unitName | productWeight | weightUnitName | deliverySchedule | sameday_code |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+----------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+------------------+-------------------+----------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------+----------+---------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+
| 4         | REPRINT     | 4               | pengembalian barang(refund) | JAKSEL         | 2020-11-13 17:51:36 | 94148181 | 94148181     | Ellin Natalia | Jalan Pati Unus No. 33, Lt. 2, KEBAYORAN BARU, KOTA JAKARTA SELATAN, DKI JAKARTA, 12120 | 089692646971 | 960-931             | 0-09-1-00960     | Ayam Fillet 500g  | REG      | 1           | 3.00            | 0.5 Kg        | 1.50              | kg       | 1.50          | Kg             | -                | PHS          |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+----------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+------------------+-------------------+----------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------+----------+---------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+
|           |             |                 |                             |                |                     |          |              |               |                                                                                         |              | 961-932             | 0-09-1-00961     | Ayam Kampung 650g | REG      | 1           | 1.00            | 0.65 Kg       | 0.65              | kg       | 0.65          | Kg             | -                | PHS          |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+----------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+------------------+-------------------+----------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------+----------+---------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+
|           |             |                 |                             |                |                     |          |              |               |                                                                                         |              | 961-932             | 0-09-1-00961     | Ayam Kampung 650g | REG      | 2           | 3.00            | 0.65 Kg       | 1.95              | kg       | 1.95          | Kg             | -                | PHS          |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+----------------+---------------------+----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+------------------+-------------------+----------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------+----------+---------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: How would you then do the difference between no value (`NULL`) and a duplicated value?

Comment: duplicated value like, if two stuff has same printStatus for rowNumber = 4 (for example) then the printStatus just appear once, not twice

Comment: Do this on the client side.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get rid of the duplicates in your select.

To avoid duplicates you would want to use [`DISTINCT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp).

Change the select to:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM mytable
WHERE rowNumber = 4;
```

Note that `DISTINCT` only excludes a row from the select, if all selected values are **equal** to those of an already found row.